# Formatting dates to dd/mm/yyyy in a Google Apps Script html template table

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, materialize

I'm developing an app in Google Apps Script to access data in sheets and display it in a html app.

I've been able to show the data regions I want from the spreadsheet, and it contains a column which store dates in a format "dd/mm/yyyy". However, when I run the html template, it shows me dates in this format: "Sat Jun 03 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)".

I'm using a materalize.css datepicker to collect. To display in the html template, I create this function (shortened here just to show the corresponding date column code):

```
function travelsTable() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);

  var sheetViagens = ss.getSheetByName("viagens");
 
  var dateViagens = sheetViagens.getRange(2,1,40,1);
  var listaDates = dateViagens.getValues();

}
```

And I store the data for column in this way (the top and foot code of the table were ommited here):

```
  for (var i = 0; i < listaDates.length; i++) {
    if (listaDates[i][0] != "") {
      linesViagens += "<tr><td class='center-align'>" + listaDates[i][0] + "</td>";
    }
```

And finally, input the variable reference in the html file like this:

```
<body>
    
      <h2 class="center-align">Dashboard de Solicitações </h2>
      <br>

      <?!= headTableViagens; ?>
      <?!= linesViagens; ?>
      <?!= footTableViagens; ?>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Any clues about how and where I can format the dates to display in html table in "dd/mm/yyyy" format? Thanks!

Comment: Utilties.formatDate()

Comment: In your situation, if the date values are put into the cells with the format of `dd/mm/yyyy` in the Spreadsheet, how about modifying from `var listaDates = dateViagens.getValues();` to `var listaDates = dateViagens.getDisplayValues();`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) By this, the display values are directly used.

Comment: Tanaike, it worked!! Thanks a lot!! \o

Answer (score 0):

[Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) comment solved my problem, so giving him credit for the answer below:

In your situation, if the date values are put into the cells with the format of `dd/mm/yyyy` in the Spreadsheet, how about modifying

from `var listaDates = dateViagens.getValues();` to `var listaDates = dateViagens.getDisplayValues();`?

[Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) By this, the display values are directly used.